# multi clinician medical clinic calendar using fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

does anybody have any experience with building a multi clinician medical clinic calendar using fullcalendar?
i am looking for a quick solution that will require scheduling appointment for clinicians.
features:

1. different type of appointment
2. receptionist view of multiple clinician schedule
3. i need to run is as a micro service integrating w/ JSP framework as the main code

have not tried yet, looking for the right solution, quick and cost effective.

Comment: Point 1 - yes fullcalendar can put any events in you want. Arguably outside the scope of the calendar itself. Point 2 can be achieved with the Resource Timeline view in fullCalendar. Point 3 is server-side and outside the scope of fullcalendar directly.

Comment: Anyway your post is off-topic - it's too broad and also apparently asking for recommendations for existing solutions (because presumably you don't expect anyone to code it up for free and put it in an Answer here...that would be asking **a lot** and isn't the purpose of this site). We can help you with _specific_ programming issues within some code you're currently trying to write. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)